# What is meant by /0 in AMD64 specification?

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit

The AMD64 specification talks about /0 with regards to instruction encoding but I don't have a clue what is meant by that. For example, in Volume 3 the ADD instruction has three forms:

ADD reg/mem16, imm16    81 /0 iw Add imm16 to reg/mem16

ADD reg/mem32, imm32    81 /0 id Add imm32 to reg/mem32.

ADD reg/mem64, imm32    81 /0 id Add sign-extended imm32 to reg/mem64.

These all use the opcode 81 followed by /0 which I presume distinguishes between the three followed by the immediate value iw or id. But what does /0 mean?

Answer (score 1):

> > FF /0
> >
> > Notation indicating that FF is the first byte of an opcode, and a subopcode in the ModR/M byte has a value of 0.

Here, for example, the ADD, ADC, and AND instructions all use opcodes 80, 81, 82, 83.  The subopcode of /0 is for ADD; the subopcode of /2 for ADC, and the subopcode /4 for AND.  The subopcode field is a 3-bit field (values /0 thru /7) that is found in the next byte, the ModR/M byte.

```
ADC reg/mem8, imm8 80 /2 ib Add imm8 to reg/mem8 + CF.
ADC reg/mem16, imm16 81 /2 iw Add imm16 to reg/mem16 + CF.
ADC reg/mem32, imm32 81 /2 id Add imm32 to reg/mem32 + CF.
ADC reg/mem64, imm32 81 /2 id Add sign-extended imm32 to reg/mem64 + CF.
ADC reg/mem16, imm8 83 /2 ib Add sign-extended imm8 to reg/mem16 + CF.
ADC reg/mem32, imm8 83 /2 ib Add sign-extended imm8 to reg/mem32 + CF.
ADC reg/mem64, imm8 83 /2 ib Add sign-extended imm8 to reg/mem64 + CF

ADD reg/mem8, imm8 80 /0 ib Add imm8 to reg/mem8.
ADD reg/mem16, imm16 81 /0 iw Add imm16 to reg/mem16
ADD reg/mem32, imm32 81 /0 id Add imm32 to reg/mem32.
ADD reg/mem64, imm32 81 /0 id Add sign-extended imm32 to reg/mem64.
ADD reg/mem16, imm8 83 /0 ib Add sign-extended imm8 to reg/mem16
ADD reg/mem32, imm8 83 /0 ib Add sign-extended imm8 to reg/mem32.
ADD reg/mem64, imm8 83 /0 ib Add sign-extended imm8 to reg/mem64.

AND reg/mem8, imm8 80 /4 ib AND the contents of reg/mem8 with imm8.
AND reg/mem16, imm16 81 /4 iw AND the contents of reg/mem16 with imm16.
AND reg/mem32, imm32 81 /4 id AND the contents of reg/mem32 with imm32.
AND reg/mem64, imm32 81 /4 id AND the contents of reg/mem64 with sign-extended imm32.
AND reg/mem16, imm8 83 /4 ib AND the contents of reg/mem16 with a sign-extended 8-bit value.
AND reg/mem32, imm8 83 /4 ib AND the contents of reg/mem32 with a sign-extended 8-bit value.
AND reg/mem64, imm8 83 /4 ib AND the contents of reg/mem64 with a sign-extended 8-bit
```